# Inserting if-else statement inside widget definition

Tags: flutter

I have inserted a TableCalendar widget inside a class in my Flutter app.

```
child: TableCalendar(
              calendarController: _calendarController,
              locale: 'es_ES',
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                todayColor: AppColors.naranjaCapenergy,
                selectedColor: AppColors.azulCapenergy,
                todayStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )
              ),
            ),
```

I am working in the app with the package easy_localization to let the user select the desired UI language.

I have included the languages english(en_EN) and spanish (es_ES).

The way I have found to get the current locale is as follows:

```
print("current locale " + context.locale.toString());
```

Inside the TableCalendar definition, I would like to change the parameter locale: depending on the current locale.
I have tried to insert an if - else statement to change the locale parameter, but I am getting an error in the editor.

Which is the recommended way to change the locale parameter inside the TableCalendar definition depending on the value of the current locale?

Comment: try `locale = (context.locale.toString() == "Your desired value")? 'en_EN':'en_ES'` .

Comment: you can make the locale a variable and use a function to change it.

Comment: @AmanVerma, it was much easier than I expected, please take a look to my own answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SrilalSachintha, it was much easier than I expected, please take a look to my own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it just inserting the current locale value, without the need to use if-else statement:

```
TableCalendar(
...
locale: context.locale.toString(),
...
)
```

Comment: You should change the title of the question then , your title asks how to insert if -else

Comment: @AmanVerma, you are right, that was my first way to handle the issue.

Comment: @AmanVerma, I have upvoted your comment, thank you.